# Filter data.table using date vector in R

Tags: r, data.table

How can I create data vector to filter data.table?

```
timeframe = as.Date(seq(ISOdate(1997,06,12), Sys.time(), "weeks")) 
timeframe2 = c("1997-06-12", "1997-06-19") 

tmp = data[Name == "aaa" & Date %in% timeframe] #doesn't return data
tmp = data[Name == "aaa" & Date %in% timeframe2] #returns data
```

tmp return data only for second timeframe2 variable (I show timeframe2 only as example to show that tmp should return data)

Comment: You only have one `timeframe` variable; you're overwriting `timeframe` with the second line.

Comment: It's just typo mistake in code. May be question should be closed.

Comment: yes. The second line should probably be `timeframe = c(timeframe, "1997-06-12", "1997-06-19")` (even though the second line isn't adding any new data to the vector)

Comment: `timeframe  <- c(timeframe, c("1997-06-12", "1997-06-19"))` should do the tirck

Comment: I edited my example to be more readable. I show timeframe2 only as example to show that tmp should return data. My question is about creating vector of date (timeframe) and using it to filter data.

Comment: If our above mentioned solutions doesn't solve your problem then please share details of your `data` dataframe.

Comment: The code you've written is valid, and it *is* how you filter a data.table using a vector. Your example and requirement is unclear. Can you update it with an example of `data`, and what you are expecting as the output?

Comment: You're probably mixing up data types. You're `timeframe2` is a character vector, whereas `timeframe` is a `Date` vector. What structure is the `Date` column in `data` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the dataframe `data` has `Date` column of type `character`. That's why filter works on `timeframe2` but the `timeframe` is of type `Date` and filter doesn't work.

One fix could be to change the type of `Date` column to `Date` in `data` **OR** other option could to convert `timeframe` as `character`. e.g :

```
timeframe  <- as.character(timeframe, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up object types. In your example, `timeframe` is a `Date` vector, whereas `timeframe2` is a `character` vector.

The 'filtering' vector will work differently depending on the type of columns you have in `data`.

Here's an example to demonstrate.

```
library(data.table)

dts <- c("2018-03-05", "2018-03-06")

## creating a data.table with 3 columns, a character, Date and POSIXct
dt <- data.table(
    date1 = dts,
    date2 = as.Date(dts),
    date3 = as.POSIXct(dts, tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
)

## create a character vector as the filter
timeframe <- c("2018-03-05")
```

**Succeeds** - Filtering a `character` column by a `character` vector

```
dt[date1 %in% timeframe]
# date1      date2      date3
# 1: 2018-03-05 2018-03-05 2018-03-05
```

**Fails** - Filtering a `Date` column by a `character` vector

```
dt[date2 %in% timeframe]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: date1,date2,date3
```

**Succeeds** - Filtering a `Date` column by a `Date` vector

```
dt[date2 %in% as.Date(timeframe)]
# date1      date2      date3
# 1: 2018-03-05 2018-03-05 2018-03-05
```

**Fails** - Filtering a `POSIXct` column by a `character` vector

```
dt[date3 %in% timeframe]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: date1,date2,date3
```

**Succeeds** - Filtering a `POSIXct` column by a `POSIXct` vector

```
dt[date3 %in% as.POSIXct(timeframe)]
#         date1      date2      date3
# 1: 2018-03-05 2018-03-05 2018-03-05
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to follow your example, but I think you're giving two examples of date vectors you might want to filter by?

If you want to filter by both, then you need to make sure you don't overwrite #1 with #2. In the second line you might want to instead use

```
timeframe = c(timeframe,"1997-06-12", "1997-06-19")
```

This will create a vector that contains all the dates you want (it just glues together the two vectors you want).

Then just filter as you already are.

Comment: No, I only want to filter tmp by timeframe. Timeframe2 is only an example.